# Datazen - Live data won't display

Tags: sql-server, business-intelligence, datazen-server

To the best of my knowledge, I'm correctly importing my MS-SQL data source in the Control Panel (It says successful in green). I'm also pretty sure I'm importing the data correctly into the Windows 7 Publisher app since I can view the data in the DataView:

[image: Data View]

but when I go to the Layout View or Run Preview, I just get a blank chart:

[image]

It works if I use the default SimulatedTable but once I change the data source to my MS-SQL table, I can't get anything to display, no matter what display element I'm trying to use.

I've tried re-importing the data, using a different MS-SQL table, and re-naming the columns to match the SimulatedTable but it doesn't change the result. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just earned the Tumbleweed badge on this one. Apparently, Microsoft can't figure it out either. I've been working with a support rep for as long as this question has been open and they are stumped to.

Comment: Having a very similar issue, data is sourced from MS-SQL fine, but the charts just won't display. I've also noticed that for example with the pie chart, the labels still display correctly, just no pie itself.

Comment: @JackR. - Yeah I'm convinced the program is just borked for Windows 7. I spent a good 20 hours or so on the phone and over Skype talking to their tech support and they never could figure it out. I eventually gave up and installed a virtual machine with Windows 8.1 so I could download the app from the Microsoft Store. Works great.

Comment: This is a good question indeed. The good thing though is that once you deploy to the server, you won't see the same issue and data would be displayed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up giving up on the Windows 7 version of the application and running a virtual instance of Windows 8.1 instead so I could install the Datazen Publisher app for Windows 8.1. It's FAR less buggy.

Not perfect, though.

Answer (score 0):

Please try one thing, I am just guessing it might work.
Please select one of the Time Preset buttons and see if you see data in that(where there is blank) chart object.
If yes, then while setting up the time navigator object, select an option in drop down box labeled "Default Time Range Preset"

There are some hacks, please do let me know if run into some weirdness. It might not make sense if i try to explain unless you run into that situation.

Cheers,